# .NET Snowflake Connector: Where to download the Snowflake .NET driver dll file, without needing to download and build the entire project from the repo

Tags: c#, .net, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The following link gives access to the Snowflake repo:
[text](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/dotnet/dotnet-driver)

To build this project it is necessary to download dependencies.

But I'm wondering of there is anywhere to download the dll file rather than the entire project as I'm not interested in changing it in any way.

I'd like to download the latest Snowflake.Data.dll file.

Comment: Is nuget not an option? [I found this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Snowflake.Data/)

Comment: If you have never used nuget before, [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget). Nuget is your one stop shop for all 3rd party dependencies in dotnet, and can even be done from command line for .NET 5+/Core. Both Visual Studio and JetBrains Rider have great GUI's to work with them as well. You download your 3rd party package, build the solution, and you are good to go. You can start importing namespaces from the package and coding with it

Comment: "If you have never used nuget before" - SERIOUISLY? Pretty much every .NET project outside a simple hello world is using nuget for .NET - it is THE dependency manager and it is what you use to incorporate basically everything into your IDE. Heck, parts of the SDK come via Nuget. You should learn using that FAST - like a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Project repo [Installing the Package](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net#installing-the-package):

> Package ID for Snowflake Connector for .Net is **Snowflake.Data**.
>
> Packages can be directly downloaded from nuget.org.
>
> It can also be downloaded using Visual Studio UI (Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Manage NuGet Packages for Solution and search for "Snowflake.Data")

---

[Drivers and Libraries - Snowflake Client Downloads](https://developers.snowflake.com/drivers-and-libraries/):

[image]

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Snowflake.Data/